# SQL Select statement and show only changed

Tags: sql

I have the simple select script and it generates following audit table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable
WHERE File = '123456A'
```

Output:

| ID | File | StatusA | StatusB | User | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456A | A | 0 | Tom | 2021-01-01 |
| 12 | 123456A | B | 0 | Jack | 2021-01-05 |
| 19 | 123456A | A | 1 | Alicia | 2021-02-09 |
| 56 | 123456A | B | 1 | Jason | 2021-03-09 |
| 87 | 123456A | A | 1 | Jason | 2021-03-10 |
| 107 | 123456A | B | 0 | Ellie | 2021-03-26 |
| 203 | 123456A | A | 0 | lucy | 2021-04-08 |
| 239 | 123456A | B | 1 | Ellie | 2021-04-16 |

I am trying to retrieve the rows when only column StatusB is changed. So it will generates the table like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable
WHERE File = '123456A' 
 -AND StatusB is changed
```

| ID | File | StatusA | StatusB | User | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456A | A | 0 | Tom | 2021-01-01 |
| 19 | 123456A | A | 1 | Alicia | 2021-02-09 |
| 107 | 123456A | B | 0 | Ellie | 2021-03-26 |
| 239 | 123456A | B | 1 | Ellie | 2021-04-16 |

In this case, I can see Alicia and Ellie changed the column StatusB. I am still thinking how to accomplish this goal.

Thanks,
-Ming

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(statusB) over (order by updatedate) as prev_statusB
      from Mytable t
      where File = '123456A' 
     ) t
where prev_statusB is null or prev_statusB <> statusB;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works prefectly. Another trick learned. Really appreciate.